# Is Nexus the right place to archive releases (jar-with-dependencies, WAR files, tar.gz, zip, etc.)?

Tags: java, maven, jar, nexus

The way I understand it, Nexus is responsible for storing JAR files that reference other dependency JARs via their pom. And, in turn, the original JAR files can be used as dependencies as well.

However, should we store release artifacts in Nexus? These are files that will never be used as dependencies. They include jar-with-dependencies, WAR files, zip/tar.gz files, etc. What's the right place to store them?

A simple file system HTTP server like http://archive.apache.org/dist/ seems to be the right idea. But Nexus is indeed just a manager on top of that.

Comment: It depends. If artifact of your project is something bigger than set of jars and wars, then it might be ok to store it there. I'd say that if you're convenient with this idea, why not? We store zip archives for some of our projects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nexus is definitely a good place to store these artifacts, since it has long evolved beyond a pure Maven repository server. It gives you a nice UI for download, security and much more.

If you are already using Nexus I would definitely not waste time with yet another server or infrastructure component to store these artifacts. Especially also if you are building your artifacts with Maven. Deployment comes pretty much for free then..

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Manser.

From my point of view, each time you release something, it should be in your Repository (Nexus, Archiva, Artifactory, whatever you want).

This is true for Enterprise Repositories,but especially true when you publish something on Internet, to keep a built version ready to use (and not ready to build ;), that's your SCM job). Even it's a jar with dependencies, its a convinient way to distribute your release.

The only bad point is that take a big place in repo, duplicating jars (for war, ear or jar-with-dependencies). But it's (at this moment) this only way to have a full version ready to execute.